# CoreData setter called from within itself

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

The setter of one of my CoreData objects is called twice. What happens is, I call the setter with a valid object, suddenly the setter gets called from within the setter, which nils the property again.

That's the stack trace:

[image]

and that's my overridden setter:

```
- (void)setDeliveryPayment:(DeliveryPay *)deliveryPayment {
   [self willChangeValueForKey:@"deliveryPayment"];
   [self setPrimitiveValue:deliveryPayment forKey:@"deliveryPayment"];
   [self didChangeValueForKey:@"deliveryPayment"];
}
```

Any advice which would point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: - (void)setDeliveryPayment:(DeliveryPay *)deliveryPayment getting called twice?

Comment: There are a lot of steps missing in that stack trace. It might help to get the whole thing-- by dragging the slider at the bottom of the stack trace panel in Xcode all the way to the right.

Comment: @Retro yes it's called twice. The second call is triggered somehow and I don't quite get why/how.

Tom, you're right there are some steps missing in the trace. Here is the complete trace. Thanks for helping.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/wpvxbyljtbk9f4s/Screenshot%202014-08-08%2009.57.25.png